# json_encode : values showing null

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
<?php
require_once (realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../includes/database.php'));

class User {
    public $email;
    public $password;

    public function find_email($email, $password) {
        global $database;
        $pswd = substr(md5($password), 0, 25);
        $results_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM tbl_users where email_id='".$email."' AND password='".$pswd."'");
        return !empty($results_array)? array_shift($results_array) : false;
   }

    public static function find_by_sql($sql){
        global $database;
        $results = $database -> query($sql);
        $object_array = array();
        while($row = $database -> fetch_array($results)){
            $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
       }
        return $object_array;
    }

    public static function instantiate($row) {
         $event   =   new self;
         foreach($row as $attribute => $value) {
             if($event -> has_attribute($attribute)) {
                 $event -> $attribute = $value;
             }
         }
         return $event;
    }
    private function has_attribute($attribute) {
        $object_vars = get_object_vars($this);
        return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {
    $result = new User();
    $result->find_email($_GET['email'], $_GET['password']);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

This is the login.php which is supposed to print out the json for the required user, but whenever I try to get the json, this is getting returned.

```
{"email":null,"password":null}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this calls for basic debugging first. At which point does what go wrong? Can you do test outputs to find out at which point the values become empty?

Comment: Where exactly are those values supposed to come from?

Comment: Please `print_r($_GET)`, also, `email_id`, is that a number or a string?

Comment: first check $result data is it containing values,nothing to do with json_encode() it simply return json_object

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've included a line on top require_once... that connects with the database.

Comment: That's nice. Where are *those values* supposed to come from?

Comment: I don't see where you're writing to the `$email` and `$password` members, so of course they're `null`. Am I just missing it? You call a function which has those symbols as arguments, but surely those shadow the members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do anything with the result of `find_email`. Your class doesn't update it's own properties when `find_email` is called. Instead, it returns a new instance of the class with the `email` and `password` properties set, so you need to capture the return value and encode that.

Change to:

```
$result = new User();
$user = $result->find_email($_GET['email'], $_GET['password']);
echo json_encode($user);
```

---

Side note: have a look at [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). DI would be preferred over having a `global $Database`.

Comment: Better yet, refactor so you don't have to create the temporary `User` object just to call `find_email`.

Comment: I agree there is a lot of room for refactoring here, the class is doing a bit too much. It seems the class is trying to be both a user entity and a user manager/factory.

Comment: This seems to fix the issue. Thanks a lot. Was working on some project, trying out php for the first time. This is a part of feeder btw, for an iOS app.

Will look into those SOLID and Dependency Injection. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. SOLID and DI can get quite complex so don't let it overwhelm you. If you just understand the basics/reasoning behind them, it will help a lot.